# Google map - which are local and utc time?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this timezone result from google map, for instance,

```
{
   "dstOffset" : 0.0,
   "rawOffset" : -28800.0,
   "status" : "OK",
   "timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",
   "timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

which one is **local** time and which one is **utc** time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**dstOffset**: the offset for daylight-savings time in seconds. This will be zero if the time zone is not in Daylight Savings Time during the specified timestamp.

**rawOffset**: the offset from UTC (in seconds) for the given location. This does not take into effect daylight savings.

**Calculating the Local Time:**
The local time of a given location is the sum of the timestamp parameter, and the **dstOffset** and **rawOffset** fields from the result.

[The Google Time zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/#Responses)

Comment: thanks for the answer and the link. but sorry for being stupid as I still don't quite understand - so rawOffset is utc time and dstOffset is the local time?

Comment: You can take UTC time from timestamp. The local time of a given location is the sum of the timestamp parameter, and the dstOffset and rawOffset fields from the result.

Comment: *you are providing a timestamp in the request (I think so)